# jQuery quickSearch plugin to fire on click of a submit button rather than event bound on input

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Am using jQuery quickSearch plugin to filter a list:

http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/

However i want to filter on click of a submit button rather than the default bindings that are supplied with the plugin itself.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
    $(function(){
    var $qs = $('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#table_example tbody tr');

    $('#mySubmit').click(function () {
        $qs.go();
        return false;
    });

});
```

With the accompanying html being:

```
<form action="#">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="search" value="" id="id_search" />
                <input type="submit" name="mySubmit" id="mySubmit" value="Search table" />              
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    <table id="table_example">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Ip</th>
                <th>Url</th>

                <th>Time</th>
                <th>ISO Date</th>
                <th>UK Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <th>devo@flexomat.com</th>

                <td>66672</td>
                <td>941-964-8535</td>
                <td>$2482.79</td>
                <td>172.78.200.124</td>

                <td>http://gmail.com</td>
                <td>15:10</td>

                <td>1988/12/14</td>
                <td>14/12/1988</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>henry@mountdev.net</th>

                <td>35889</td>

                <td>941-964-9543</td>
                <td>$2776.09</td>
                <td>119.232.182.142</td>

                <td>http://www.gmail.com</td>
                <td>3:54</td>

                <td>1974/1/19</td>

                <td>19/1/1974</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>christian@reno.gov</th>
                <td>60021</td>
                <td>941-964-5617</td>

                <td>$2743.41</td>
                <td>167.209.64.181</td>

                <td>http://www.dotnet.ca</td>
                <td>10:58</td>
                <td>2000/3/25</td>
                <td>25/3/2000</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>muffins@donuts.com</th>
                <td>17927</td>
                <td>941-964-9511</td>
                <td>$2998.18</td>

                <td>210.214.231.182</td>

                <td>http://google.se</td>
                <td>21:22</td>
                <td>1993/1/24</td>
                <td>24/1/1993</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>muffins@reno.gov</th>

                <td>76375</td>
                <td>941-964-2757</td>
                <td>$1836.09</td>
                <td>220.222.93.171</td>

                <td>http://www.samba.org</td>
                <td>15:22</td>

                <td>1988/4/4</td>
                <td>4/4/1988</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>mendez@gmail.com</th>
                <td>45834</td>
                <td>941-964-2575</td>

                <td>$2805.46</td>
                <td>228.170.245.253</td>

                <td>http://flexomat.com</td>

                <td>11:31</td>
                <td>1975/12/12</td>
                <td>12/12/1975</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>dev@gmail.com</th>

                <td>20022</td>
                <td>941-964-4967</td>
                <td>$3296.54</td>
                <td>175.248.70.240</td>

                <td>http://www.flexomat.com</td>
                <td>4:27</td>

                <td>2002/7/3</td>
                <td>3/7/2002</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>foo@polyester.se</th>

                <td>55977</td>

                <td>941-964-745</td>
                <td>$2953.73</td>
                <td>222.114.227.156</td>

                <td>http://www.donuts.com</td>
                <td>23:49</td>

                <td>1977/8/4</td>

                <td>4/8/1977</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>adam@aftonbladet.se</th>
                <td>38867</td>
                <td>941-964-6302</td>

                <td>$1949.27</td>
                <td>116.241.143.196</td>

                <td>http://flexomat.com</td>
                <td>23:35</td>
                <td>1995/7/27</td>
                <td>27/7/1995</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>devo@donuts.com</th>
                <td>51426</td>
                <td>941-964-1234</td>
                <td>$1067.00</td>

                <td>88.96.149.82</td>

                <td>http://www.polyester.se</td>
                <td>15:17</td>
                <td>1986/1/5</td>
                <td>5/1/1986</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>

                <th>henry@samba.org</th>

                <td>40859</td>
                <td>941-964-4856</td>
                <td>$3401.19</td>
                <td>68.152.250.74</td>

                <td>http://www.flexomat.com</td>
                <td>4:36</td>

                <td>1990/3/7</td>
                <td>7/3/1990</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>found@dotnet.ca</th>
                <td>23986</td>
                <td>941-964-2686</td>

                <td>$1393.52</td>
                <td>98.102.181.138</td>

                <td>http://lostnfound.org</td>

                <td>5:51</td>
                <td>1993/7/22</td>
                <td>22/7/1993</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>carl@fish.org</th>

                <td>73392</td>
                <td>941-964-5792</td>
                <td>$3876.04</td>
                <td>246.234.182.243</td>

                <td>http://www.google.se</td>
                <td>6:52</td>

                <td>1984/7/14</td>
                <td>14/7/1984</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>found@mountdev.net</th>

                <td>03519</td>

                <td>941-964-1599</td>
                <td>$1176.48</td>
                <td>104.212.122.177</td>

                <td>http://donutsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com</td>
                <td>18:52</td>

                <td>2000/8/6</td>

                <td>6/8/2000</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and found no solution online so I spent a little time in the plugin and found a solution that worked for me.  The plugin uses the keyup event to fire so I applied a trigger to the quicksearch textbox that calls the keyup event.  For your example I believe the following would work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

   var $qs = $('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#table_example tbody tr');   

   $('#mySubmit').click(function () {         
       $('#id_search').trigger("keyup");      
       return false;     
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the update.  I didn't even remember posting this until now.  The project is using Datatables plugin now for a similar effect but in a server side implementation with great success.

Comment: I might be using a different version of quicksearch, but mine overwrote the `trigger` function so I had to monkeypatch a copy of the original trigger function to call later: `var triggerFilter = $input.trigger.bind($input)`